# XCode debugger unexpectedly switches current execution line

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

The strangest thing is happening when I am trying to debug this code:

```
- (IBAction)showNextMeal:(id)sender {
    unsigned int flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate* currentTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSArray* todays = [self MealsForDay:DayOfWeek];
    int segueid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        NSDate * startTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:flags fromDate:[[todays objectAtIndex:i] End]]];
        NSComparisonResult c = [currentTime compare:startTime];

        if (c == NSOrderedAscending) {
            segueid = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:segueid inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MealSegue" sender:self];
}
```

The code runs fine up until the third to last line (`NSIndexPath* indexPath`) than it jumps back to `int segueid = 0` and runs again. After if figures itself out, the iphone performs TWO segues to the same place.

I have screen captured the debugging so you can see exactly what I am talking about.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SR-O5Xhsqk

Why is the computer jumping around the code, and why is it preforming TWO segues to the same place?

Comment: You sure it's **not** because of the loop?

Comment: None of the weird code in inside of the loop. the loop starts after I define `segueid`

Comment: Sounds like the loop to me.  The debugger will often do some funny jumping back and forth at the end of each loop iteration.  Has nothing to do with the actual code flow, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) If you are debugging optimized code, execution order can be weird (but the compiler will never re-order execution in a way that changes behavior -- barring bugs).  But that is unlikely in play here due to the double segues.

(2) Drop in a couple of NSLog() statements to see if it really is being doubly executed.

(3) The most common cause of this kind of thing is threading; some bit of code running in a queue that runs through this code path that then triggers an update or some behavior on the main queue.   If you do `NSLog(@"%p", [NSThread currentThread]);` that'll log the thread's address.  If it is different on the two different executions of that method, there's you're problem.

(Note that when you "step" while debugging, other threads in your app will run during the step.  This is required because it is trivially easy to deadlock otherwise.)

Comment: I am trying the NSLogs right now. I will get back to you once I have tested it.

Comment: This really helped figure it out. I dropped these in, and found that they weren't even being executed. Clean & build and everything was right in the world.

Comment: Ssspooookkky.... I hate bugs like that.  Sounds like the build state got out of sync.

Comment: Its what happens when you trust that xcode always knows what its doing :) `Clean and Build` should really be a requirement before questions are posted.